# Is there a possibility of seeing a graph of a question's views over time?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, views, data-analysis

I'm not sure if this is possible architecturally, but when judging whether to set a bounty and how much it should be, it would be nice to see the impact based on our previous questions. If you're not visiting the site throughout the day, there is no way to tell how effective that bounty might be--particularly for increasing traffic. There is a similar question with adding and removing tags that increase the visibility in the right places, and the effect on views that may have.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't store this data over time, so aside from the view count from one data dump to the next, we have no more granular data available than that.

That's not to say we *couldn't* start storing this...but it wouldn't be good for the past, and it would be much more expensive (for not a lot of gain), since we handle quite a few views.

Comment: So you are saying I was right? `:)`

Comment: @jjnguy - oh didn't notice an answer before I tabbed back here...I was answering then for distracted by unicorns and team chat =P But yes, you're *mostly* right...except there is some historical data in the dumps.

Comment: those silly unicorns...always being distracting and stuff...

Comment: Thanks--I figured that may be the case. What about the possibility of specific trackers, say a snapshot of the views every hour for questions with a bounty?

Comment: Any updates, two years later? :)

Comment: I've never really looked but this sounds like the sort of thing you could poll the API for, if you're interested in a specific question, assuming nothing else has changed...

Comment: You have the time of all individual votes (account -> activity -> votes). So what's missing?

Comment: @MartinSchröder view count is what's being discussed here. Different than votes.

Answer (score 3):

(Unofficial answer)

No.  The views data is only stored as a simple counter.  No historical data is kept, thus there is no way to present a graph of views over time.

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong - you store the complete individual vote history.

Comment: @MartinSchröder they are asking about view history.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

[image]

But you can only chart the future, not the past.

I wrote a script to keep track of views to your questions over time.  Set it up to run once a day: https://github.com/SurpriseDog/se.views

After a few weeks you can run the included graphing utility to make fun graphs like this one.

It requires StackAPI which you can get with: `pip3 install StackAPI`