# Post view count: statistics/graph

Tags: feature-request, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [It there a possibility of seeing a graph of a question’s views over time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92554/it-there-a-possibility-of-seeing-a-graph-of-a-questions-views-over-time)

I think it would be interesting to be able to see a question's/post's view count not only as a total count but also broken down over time, preferably as a graph. Similar to the rep graph that is provided in the user's profile.

Such tool *could* give valuable insight to if a specific question was popular at a certain point of time, if the interest of the topic/problem is increasing or declining, or if the topic has an even distribution of interest over time. Supposedly it could also be interesting for specific topics to spot trends as technology advances, bugs are fixed, and new SDKs are released, and so on.

This is of course not a high priority request, but I'd like to know if the community and the devs think this would be a nice-to-have feature, or if there are good arguments why this is a bad idea. Maybe the view count is just a counter in a DB, and this feature is not possible to implement.

---

Update: Let me rephrase question after the posts by Tim and Yanniz: Would it be possible to plot the votes as a graph instead, as a part of the post's timeline?

Comment: @TimStone: Thanks, that answer the question. I didn't find that one prior to asking my own.

Comment: I'm assuming you know questions have a timeline? If not, well [here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227809/timeline). Not the same as your feature, but it does give hints for the question's popularity over time.

Comment: @YannisRizos: No, I had no idea. How to you reach that info from the question itself?

Comment: @AvadaKedavra See the url, it's essentially `posts/<question id>/timeline`

Comment: @YannisRizos: Yeah, cheers. That gives some hit of the popularity over time. It may not give the same coverage, but it is a step on the way, and probably the only feasible data to get given that the view count is just a counter in the DB. Would still be interesting to see each vote as a graph.

Comment: You may also be interested in [Plot upvotes over time for an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148445)

Comment: @TimStone: Heh, you answered my follow-up question as I was writing it :)